# "Is" or "are" when one item is singular, the other plural

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is, disjunction

Would you say:

> There **is** no fire or hot ashes in the fireplace.

or

> There **are** no fire or hot ashes in the fireplace.

And where does that question mark go?

Comment: Use *neither* and *nor*. "There is neither A nor B" is the construction used when you want to say that both A and B aren't there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has a definitive answer at the thread tchrist points to.

Comment: Wrt the question-mark-after a choice of sentences, you either rephrase, or risk the good-style-is-as-important-as-grammar police and put it where it seems logical: after the second period (and here on a new line after the second blockquote).

Comment: What question mark?

Answer (score 0):

> "There's no fire or hot ashes in the fireplace."

Neither "is" nor "are" sounds right.  With "there's", you avoid the issue, since many accept that with a plural subject.

Another possibility is:

> There is no fire, or hot ashes either, in the fireplace.

This avoids the problem, because the main verb does not agree with something within a parenthetical expression or aside.